# Multiple IF functions on a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, google, worksheet-function, if-this-then-that, google-sheets-cell-format

How do I add multiple IF functions on 1 cel, without blocking it on the first line.
As you can see, column D contains a bunch of text. In column A, I want to categories them.

It works up until the first line, but it gives and error because he doesn't find "wheel".
I want it to ignore this, and just go to the second line when he doesn't find "wheel", etc

See image below

Can anyone help me?

[image]

---

Would you know how to fix this problem?
IF the word "paypal" is in cel D, AND there is a specific amount in cel C, I want it to categorize it.

See image.

[image: image1]

Answer (score 2):

Matter is with SEARCH() returning error when failing to find your criteria.

To avoid that wrap your SEARCH() in IFERROR() like this:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("wheel", A41),),"car",
 IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("banana", A41),),"fruit","No matches"))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lloyd If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left